# Имитация событий selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт qunar.com Я хочу с помощью selenium web driver на java в поле input ввести текст, но мне пишет что element not visible. На элементе висят обработчики событий вида keyUp, keyDown, focus. Как на web driver имитировать эти события keyUp, keyDown, focus.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pryanichnikov\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.qunar.com/");

    WebElement tabButton = driver.findElement(By.id("js_inter_tab"));
    tabButton.click();

    WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'fromCity')]"));
    input.sendKeys("SFO");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pryanichnikov\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.qunar.com/");

    WebElement tabButton = driver.findElement(By.id("js_inter_tab"));
    tabButton.click();

    WebElement oneWayFlightRadioButton = driver.findElement(By.id("js_intersearchtype_oneway"));
    oneWayFlightRadioButton.click();

    WebElement divForFromCityInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]"));
    divForFromCityInput.click();

    divForFromCityInput.sendKeys("SFO");
```